# @BeforeScenario / @AfterScenario to Specific Scenario in Test Story by using Given

Tags: jbehave

I am a newbie to JBheave and Hive frameworks.

While exploring Q&A repositories, I happen to see the following phrase from one of right Answer to a Question,-

[writing a JBehave story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704223/writing-a-jbehave-story)

> That's what I've seen - and the data object should be setup/cleared
>   with a @BeforeScenario/@AfterScenario method.

At present I am in the process of writing Test Stories. Yet not get into Steps further.

From the JBehave product website, I get the following sample Test Story. I have Question considering the phrase which I plugged out from the Q&A repo of StackOverFlow.

```
A story is a collection of scenarios

Narrative:
In order to communicate effectively to the business some functionality
As a development team
I want to use Behaviour-Driven Development

Lifecycle:
Before:
Given a step that is executed before each scenario
After:
Outcome: ANY   
Given a step that is executed after each scenario regardless of outcome
Outcome: SUCCESS
Given a step that is executed after each successful scenario
Outcome: FAILURE
Given a step that is executed after each failed scenario

Scenario:  A scenario is a collection of executable steps of different type

Given step represents a precondition to an event
When step represents the occurrence of the event
Then step represents the outcome of the event

Scenario:  Another scenario exploring different combination of events

Given a [precondition]
When a negative event occurs
Then a the outcome should [be-captured]   

Examples:
|precondition|be-captured|
|abc|be captured    |
|xyz|not be captured|
```

I could see the pretty same just as like @BeforeScenario/@AfterScenario over here.

I do have Question here. Is I could write `Given` before and after to specific `Scenario:` in a Test Story.

And is that `Scenario:` output is open to consecutive `Scenario:`'s in the Test Story.

Answer (score 7):

There is a few differences between @BeforeScenario/@AfterScenario annotations and Lifecycle:Before/After steps

1. A java method annotated with @BeforeScenario or @AfterScenario is called **for all** executed scenarios **in all stories**, while a Lifecycle-Before or -After step will be executed only for scenarios **from this one, concrete story**.
2. @AfterScenario method is executed always, regardless of a result of the scenario. Lifecycle After steps can be called always (using Outcome: ANY clause), only on failures (using Outcome: Failure clause) or only on success (using Outcome: SUCCESS clause)
3. You cannot pass any parameters from a scenario (story) to @BeforeScenario and @AfterScenario java methods, while Lifecycle steps can have parameters, like any other ordinary steps, for example:

---

```
Lifecycle:
Before:
Given a step that is executed before each scenario with some parameter = 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your good answer. However in my case my test story `then` clause may go very complicated with several `and` clause and so and so constraints. I need that to be passed as a parameter to the next scenario or some. Will there will be way for it?

Comment: Please explain in more details your specific case, preferably as a new questions  - what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: how to map a parameter written in the story to the method annotated with @BeforeScenario ?

Comment: @EnricoGiurin you may store the parameter in some global variable and then to use it within the AfterScenario method

Answer (score -2):

JBehave is for Data Mining. And it is uses Test Driven Development, TDD. We call that as Steps. BDD - Behavior Driven Development, that yields the Mining capability of that framework injected towards any Higher-Level language.

Answering the Question,- In a test story, if we put `Scenario` in the mid of two `then` statements, it clears the buffers as it is a new scenario. That way `Given` clause datasets is applied as-is, rather implied. That way `Given` clause values are taken forward. For new `Scenario` only `Lifecycle` prerequisites which is been set is only applied on before and after respectively.

Comment: Thanks for my colleague Rob for giving clarity for this doubt! Yep I yet to strive on Hive based frameworks however. Thanks Once again!